# How to combine array from an array with similar id?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Suppose I have a array like this.

```
const info = [
    {
        productId: "1",
        name: "This is product name 1",
        sellerId: "12",
        price: 30,
    },
    {
        productId: "2",
        name: "This is product name 2",
        sellerId: "12",
        price: 50
    },
    {
        productId: "3",
        name: "This is product name 3",
        sellerId: "13",
        price: 50
    }
]
```

**This is dynamic array. Array value can be changed.

Now I have to combine this array or filter this array. I have not any idea about how can I write function. But my result will be like this-

```
const result = [
    {
        sellerId: "12",
        productIds: [ //Combine products by similar sellerId
            {
                name: "This is product name 1",
                productId: "1"
            },
            {
                name: "This is product name 2",
                productId: "2"
            }
        ],
        total: 80 //Total price of this two product
    },
    {
        sellerId: "13",
        productIds: [
            {
                name: "This is product name 3",
                productId: "3"
            }
        ],
        total: 50
    }
]
```

Please do not close my question. I almost check all similar questions. But I have a different issue here. Just please help me.

Comment: so, it seems that you are wanting to combine two arrays, but you seem to only give one and then the result seems to be the expected outcome. Or are you just asking how to make the array info to look like array result?

Comment: Yes. I want to convert `info` array like `result` array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `.reduce` and check if you already have that sellerId, if so, push the item and update total, else create the item:

```js
const info = [
    {
        productId: "1",
        name: "This is product name 1",
        sellerId: "12",
        price: 30,
    },
    {
        productId: "2",
        name: "This is product name 2",
        sellerId: "12",
        price: 50
    },
    {
        productId: "3",
        name: "This is product name 3",
        sellerId: "13",
        price: 50
    }
]

const result = info.reduce((carry, el) => {
    const { sellerId, price, ...rest } = el;
    const i = carry.find((c) => c.sellerId === sellerId);

    if (!i) {
         carry.push({ sellerId, productIds: [rest], total: price })
    } else {
        i.productIds.push(rest);
        i.total += price;
    }
    return carry;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values()` and `Array#reduce()` methods as follows:

```js
const 
    input = [ { productId: "1", name: "This is product name 1", sellerId: "12", price: 30, }, { productId: "2", name: "This is product name 2", sellerId: "12", price: 50 }, { productId: "3", name: "This is product name 3", sellerId: "13", price: 50 } ],
    
    output = Object.values(
      input.reduce(
        (acc,{productId,name,sellerId,price}) =>
        ({
            ...acc,
            [sellerId]:{...(acc[sellerId] || {}), 
                sellerId, 
                productIds: [...(acc[sellerId] && acc[sellerId]['productIds'] || []), 
                {name,productId}]
            }
        }),
      {})
    );
    
    console.log( output );
```